# invite app user to event

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I am interested if there is a possibility to invite APP users to public event on Facebook over Graph API. Note that I mean APP users, not a friends of authorized APP user but only app users themselves.

I know that there is a possibility to invite users by making POST call to /EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER_ID1,...,USER_IDn to invite multiple users but it must be made with user's access token and invites can only be sent to the friends of the token owner. I know also that app user can be set as attending if given rsvp_event permission, but I need only to send them regular event invite.

I tried to find an answer here and on facebook dev but with no avail. Thank you.